# How to Apply Sort Parameters to CM GetList and GetSearchResults Methods?

Tags: core-service

I am trying to figure out how to retrieve the latest modified X number of components from a given publication and I've been staring at the Core Service API for ages trying to figure it out. Help!

The best I got is to latch on to the `ModifiedAfter` and/or `ModifiedBefore` search parameters in the `SearchQueryData` class.

So here is what I got so far for my filter:

```
        var filter = new SearchQueryData { ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Component }, SearchInSubtree = true };
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(publicationId))
        {
            filter.FromRepository = new LinkToRepositoryData() { IdRef = publicationId };
        }

        if(resultLimit > 0)
        {
            filter.ResultLimit = resultLimit;
        }
```

All I need is a Sort Parameter property like on the CD side. Grrr!

Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: My General rule of thumb with the Core Service/TOM.NET API is: If it isn't possible in the GUI, then its probably not easy to do with the core service... As you can't pre-define a sort on a search query in the GUI I guess you are out of luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the best you can use is use the `ModifiedAfter` and `ResultLimit` do so something like:

- Get results from last month
- Take the top 5 from those
- If the list is less than 5 from last month, either live with it, or query again ?

Depending on the expected volume of updates this might be a solution for you, but i'd love someone to correct me on it too cause this is a bit of a hacky solution

Comment: The problem with specifying the ResultLimit is that Tridion doesn't always give you the latest dated items within that limit.  What you get is the first X (e.g. 5) that it returns, which is in alphanumeric order just like in the GUI.  I think a blended approach between what you're suggesting regarding ModifiedAfter (to limit the resultset to a date) and what Chris proposed (to get the sorted top x results) would work best; though I got lazy and implemented it using ResultLimit anyways.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible via CoreService.

In conjunction with John's suggestion, you could further limit the results set by restricting the search with additional filters like folder using:

```
filter.SearchIn = new LinkToIdentifiableObjectData { IdRef = folderId };
```

Then sort the results locally like

```
foreach (var item in items.OrderByDescending(x=>x.VersionInfo.RevisionDate.Value))
{
   //output
}
```

As Will mentions, if you do a search in the GUI all sorting is done client side

Comment: +1 for showing some sexy sorting linq code, and for the suggestion. In my instance the scope is latest content within a Publication, so the folder-based approach won't work, and getting all the items out of a pub and then sorting would require a pretty heavy web service response.